# An atlas with two charts

Tags: differential-geometry

On page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoordinateChart.html write that "A coordinate chart is a way of expressing the points of a small neighborhood, usually on a manifold M, as coordinates in Euclidean space. An example from geography is the coordinate chart given by the functions of latitude and longitude. This coordinate chart is not valid on the whole globe, since it doesn't give unique coordinates at the north or south pole". I am thinking that generally there is not any atlas in sphere S^n which constists of a chart only. Does anyone have a proof of this?

Comment: such a chart would have to be a homeomorphism of an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $S^n$. prove that this is not possible

Comment: It's possible to get everything except a single point from a sphere (of any dimension) into a chart (see [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)). Proving that you cannot do better requires a little thought, though, and at least some familiarity with basic topological concepts (such as compactness).

Comment: @Arthur 
 
my first idea was this one with the homeomorphism but i cannnot find the contraddiction. We know that sphere is closed and compact set so the same should apply and for its image in R^n – user391120 7 hours ago

Comment: You're nearly there. If our function is a homeomorphism, what _is_ the image? Is that compact?

Comment: @Arthur It is a compact space but i cannot see the contradiction because a subset of R^n may be compact, aright?

Comment: That is true. But can an _open_ subset of $\Bbb R^n$ be compact? Because that's part of the definition of a chart.

Comment: @Arthur My problem is this exactly.The sphere is a closed set in R^n or i am wrong?

Comment: @user391120 You are a bit wrong. See, the sphere (in this case $S^n$) is usually visualised as a closed subset in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. However, for the definition of manifold, we need charts that are homeomorphisms between open subsets of the sphere and open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$. If we have a single chart that covers all of $S^n$, then we need a homeomorphism from the compact sphere to a compact, open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. This is clearly not possible.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. I was so confused that i was thinking sphere in the same way as subset of R^n and as a manifold. Thank you for your answers.